# Yii2 kartik-datecontrol timepicker Update

Tags: php, yii2, timepicker

I am using a DateControl widget by Kartik in my Yii2-powered system. The widget correctly saves the time I've selected. However, when I tried to update the data, it just always shows "12:30" as the time and not the time from the database. I am still new to Yii2 and I there's not much information on the Internet regarding this issue. Thank you for the help!

Code for my form:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'class_start_time')->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
       'type'=>DateControl::FORMAT_TIME,
       ])
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'class_end_time')->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
       'type'=>DateControl::FORMAT_TIME, 
       ])
    ?>
```

Code for the config:

```
           'displaySettings' => [
                Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'HH:mm a',
                Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a', 
            ],

            // format settings for saving each date attribute (PHP format example)
            'saveSettings' => [
                Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'php:U', // saves as unix timestamp
                Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'php:H:i:s',
                Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The `displaySettings` should be `hh:mm a` and not `HH:mm a`. There is a mismatch in the format which causes the display to be in error when the time is in PM (or greater than 12:00:00).